# What is the reason for this sysgen error?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, embedded, windows-ce

(Windows CE 7)

If i give "clean sysgen" (blddemo clean -q), i'm getting following errors:

```
SYSGEN: BUILDMSG: Found localized resources for Languages ( 0404 0407 0409 040c 0410 0411 0412 0413 0416 0419 041d 0804 0c0a)
Res2Res: ERROR: Failed CreateFileW("C:\DOCUME~1\KESHAV~1.IWA\LOCALS~1\Temp\R2R1000.tmp", RW, RW, 0, Existing, Normal, 0), GetLastError = 5. {log="C:\WINCE700\build.log(18570)"}
Res2Res: ERROR: Failed CreateFileW("C:\DOCUME~1\KESHAV~1.IWA\LOCALS~1\Temp\R2R1000.tmp", RW, RW, 0, Existing, Normal, 0), GetLastError = 5. {log="C:\WINCE700\build.log(18571)"}
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\WINCE700\public\common\oak\Bin\i386\res2res.EXE' : return code '0xffffffff' {log="C:\WINCE700\build.log(18572)"}
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\WINCE700\sdk\bin\i386\nmake.exe' : return code '0x2' {log="C:\WINCE700\build.log(18574)"}
SYSGEN: ERROR: error(s) in sysgen phase ( ie7 ) {log="C:\WINCE700\build.log(18576)"}
```

(Error list:

[image: Error list: Clean Sysgen])

Later, if i give "sysgen" (blddemo -q), there will not be any errors and build successful.

What is the reason of this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was because of Antivirus agent (Symantec Endpoint Protection) running on my system.

It is solved by disabling the SEP program.

Answer (score 1):

Error code 5 is [ACCESS_DENIED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Are you running with administrative privileges on your build machine?

Comment: You can turn off UAC. There may be ways to poke holes in UAC specifically for build programs. I don't know.